# Highlighting two radio buttons at once

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to build an app in flutter in which during quiz, I'm using radio buttons. I want to highlight the correct answer and the answer selected by the user if the correct answer is not selected by the user.

If the correct answer is selected then I just want to select the user selected answer.

I cannot find any way to do it.

```
child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              widget.content.getQuestion(),
              style: Constants.articleQuestionStyle,
            ),
            Container(),
            Column(
                children: widget.content
                    .getOptions()
                    .map<Widget>((value)  => _buildRadioBtn(value))
                    .toList()),

//
//                {
//                  return Row(children: [
//                    Radio(
//                      value: value,
//                      groupValue: widget.content.getGuess(),
//                      onChanged: (val){
//                        print("value:  ${value}");
//                        print("isChecked:  ${widget.content.isChecked()}");
//                        return //_buildRadioBtn(val);
////                                widget.content.isChecked()
////                                  ? null :
//                          _buildRadioBtn(val);//_handleValueChanged(val);
//                      },
//                      activeColor: (widget.content.getGuess() == widget.content.getCorrectAnswer())? Colors.orange: Colors.red,
//                    ),
//
//                    Text(
//                      value,
//                      style: Constants.articleBodyTextStyle,
//                    )
//                  ]);
//                }
//                ).toList()),
```

and

```
  _buildRadioBtn(value) {
//    bool isCorrect = widget.content.getCorrectAnswer().contains(value);
//    bool isChosen = widget.content.getGuess().contains(value);
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Radio(
          value: widget.content.isChecked(),
          groupValue: widget.content.getGuess(),
          onChanged: (value){
            if(!widget.content.isChecked()) {
//              print("ffffff");
//              widget.content.registerGuess(value);
//              print("abc");
//              setState(() {});
            _handleValueChanged(value);
            }
          },
          activeColor: (
              widget.content.getGuess() == widget.content.getCorrectAnswer())? Colors.orange: Colors.red,
        ),

        Text(
//          "hello",
          value,
          style: Constants.articleBodyTextStyle,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The way I think it will work is to rebuild the radio button once the user selects the answer, but I cannot do so. Please help.

Comment: Can you share the code sample for the same? 
As far as I understand you want to highlight the answer if the answer is correct?

Comment: Share your code, so people can suggest improvement and fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method: 1**

```
String question = 'Q 1', answer = 'A 3', defaultValue = 'nil';
      List<String> options = ['A 1', 'A 2', 'A 3', 'A 4'], info = ['', '', '', ''];
      List<Color> bgs = [Colors.white, Colors.white, Colors.white, Colors.white];

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(title: Text(question)),
                ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: options.length,
                    itemBuilder: (cc, ii) {
                      return Card(
                        color: bgs[ii],
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(options[ii]),
                          subtitle: Text(info[ii]),
                          leading: Radio(
                            value: options[ii],
                            groupValue: defaultValue,
                            onChanged: (String value) {
                              setState(() {
                                defaultValue = value;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
                RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (defaultValue == answer) {
                        setState(() {
                          int ind = options.indexOf(defaultValue);
                          bgs[ind] = Colors.green;
                          info[ind] = 'Correct Answer !';
                        });
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          int wrongInd = options.indexOf(defaultValue);
                          bgs[wrongInd] = Colors.redAccent;
                          info[wrongInd] = 'Wrong Answer !';
                          int correctInd = options.indexOf(answer);
                          bgs[correctInd] = Colors.green;
                          info[correctInd] = 'Correct Answer !';
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text('Submit'))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

[image: Output]

**Method: 2**

```
String question = 'Q 1', answer = 'A 3', defaultValue = 'nil';
  List<String> options = ['A 1', 'A 2', 'A 3', 'A 4'], info = ['', '', '', ''],radioValues=[];
  List<Color> bgs = [Colors.black, Colors.black, Colors.black, Colors.black];

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    radioValues.addAll(options);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(title: Text(question)),
            ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: options.length,
                itemBuilder: (cc, ii) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(options[ii],
                               style:TextStyle(color:bgs[ii])),
                    subtitle: Text(info[ii],
                                  style:TextStyle(color:bgs[ii])),
                    leading: Radio(
                      value: radioValues[ii],
                      groupValue: defaultValue,
                      onChanged: (String value) {
                        setState(() {
                          defaultValue = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }),
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (defaultValue == answer) {
                    setState(() {
                      int ind = options.indexOf(defaultValue);
                      bgs[ind] = Colors.green;
                      info[ind] = 'Correct Answer !';
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      int wrongInd = options.indexOf(defaultValue);
                      bgs[wrongInd] = Colors.redAccent;
                      info[wrongInd] = 'Wrong Answer !';
                      int correctInd = options.indexOf(answer);
                      bgs[correctInd] = Colors.green;
                      info[correctInd] = 'Correct Answer !';
                      radioValues[wrongInd] = defaultValue;
                      radioValues[correctInd] = defaultValue;
                    });
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Submit'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: Method 2]

Comment: Hi, thanks but can you provide some solution which does not involve cards. I am trying to rebuild the radio button once the user selects and option but am unable to do so. Please help.

Comment: Then remove Card widget and use text color to show correct and wrong answers inside the ListTile texts !

Comment: I added 2nd method ! Check it ! If worked for you accept the answer !

Comment: @NaveenAvidi only one radio button at a time is highlighted, when passing `defaultValue` to `groupValue`parameter( which is the intended behaviour),how  do you highlight more than one radio ??

Comment: use checkbox list tile or maintain a list of selected items and use radio value as list.contains item !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you leave the select state of what the user picked. What you can do is change the colors or styling of the text of the items to reflect which the user picked vs which is the correct answer.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can show me the code.

Comment: Can you first post the part of the `build()` that outputs the radio buttons?